# Custom rails routing with has_many not working with form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Trying to make a custom route for rails with has_many

This is my model for 'Animes'

```
has_many :anime_categories, dependent: :destroy
```

This is the route I have made

```
 match 'animes/:id/categories/new' => 'anime_categories#new', :via => :get
```

problem is when i visit /animes/animename/categories/new i'm getting a no method error which is raised from form_for:

```
NoMethodError in AnimeCategories#new
Showing     

app/views/anime_categories/new.html.erb where line #11 raised:

undefined method `anime_categories_path' for #<#    <Class:0x007fb643147d40>:0x007fb6431365b8>
```

here is line 11

```
 <%= form_for(@anime_category) do |f| %>
```

AnimeCategory new method:

```
class AnimeCategoriesController < ApplicationController
 def new

@anime = Anime.friendly.find(params[:id])
@anime_category = Anime.friendly.find(@anime.id).anime_categories.new

end
```

Cant see what exactly is causing the problem. I have the 'new' method in the anime categories controller so I think its a routing problem.

I would like to keep the url format the way it is. How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned method in form_for, so in your case it will take it by default as post method. And the route you have defined is the :get method.

And on form_for you should specify create method path and not the post method path.

I am not sure about your use case but if you want to redirect to new

```
<%= form_for(@anime_category, method: :get) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I've just been using resources for routes. For forms i though it was a get on the 'new' method and a post on the 'create' method by default because of this i also have the route `match 'animes/:id/categories' => 'anime_categories#create', :via => :post`. Why would resources :anime_categories have that setup if it isn't the default? and the added get specifier hasn't work. Still the exact same error